# How to get the published version of my own article?

Tags: publications, journals

My article has been published in "Sensor Letters" journal in September 2016.  But, we have not yet received the published version of the article. Since that time, we have sent several emails to the  editor-in-chief of the Journal. Also we even called him, but I haven't received my article yet. What can I do about this problem (getting the article from the journal)?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the perceived "problem"? Don't you have institutional access to the journal?

Comment: it might sound strange, but have you checked your 'spam folder'? Some publisher just send a link to the published article, once it is published online, and maybe your email program has perceived it as 'spam/junk'?

Comment: Just order a copy. It's only $113 plus tax. Surely the article is worth spending a little bit of money on?

Comment: Ask a friend or a peer.

Comment: [*Sensor Letters*](http://www.aspbs.com/sensorlett/) or [*IEEE Sensor Letters*](http://ieee-sensors.org/senslet/)?

Comment: Technically, I don't think they have to send you a copy. It all depends on the copyright transfer / publishing agreement form that you signed, but I don't recall ever seeing it mentioned in one (at least in my field).

Comment: @CodesInChaos  You're joking, right?

Comment: @NateEldredge The [former](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/asp/senlet/2016/00000014/00000009/art00007)

Comment: Give us the full reference and I'm sure someone can dig it up for you!